# Print stacktrace in Mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

I need to modify existing C app and print stacktrace at certain place. How can I do this?

I can't compile this source:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#ifndef __USE_GNU
#define __USE_GNU
#endif

#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
 void *             array[50];
 void *             caller_address;
 char **            messages;

 int size = backtrace(array, 50);

 /* overwrite sigaction with caller's address */
 array[1] = caller_address;

 messages = backtrace_symbols(array, size);

 /* skip first stack frame (points here) */
 for (int i = 1; i < size && messages != NULL; ++i)
 {
  fprintf(stderr, "[bt]: (%d) %s\n", i, messages[i]);
 }

 free(messages);


}
```

because it lacks some symbols:

```
$ i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -rdynamic ./trace.cpp -I/usr/include/
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
./trace.cpp:39:2: warning: no newline at end of file
/tmp/cc6hCJtU.o:trace.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `_backtrace'
/tmp/cc6hCJtU.o:trace.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `_backtrace_symbols'
/tmp/cc6hCJtU.o:trace.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `_stderr'
```

I didn't manage to file proper .a file.

Following answers, that can be found here on stackoverflow are practically unusable:

- libunwind causes compile error during crosscompiling: error: ucontext.h: No such file or directory
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack doesn't compile in MinGW
- http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/code/dbg also doesn't compile
- http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/code/stack_trace also doesn't compile and has errors

Is there any working solution? Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: :: i do want a debugger implementation can you please guide me what you did for your project + Also can you post me the sample implementation that you did.it would do a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MinGW toolchain doesn't have support for the -rdynamic flag and cannot compile your application using `backtrace()` or `backtrace_symbols()`

Not sure what MinGW you are using but I would recommend getting a fresh one from here: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Are you suggesting the latest MinGW fixes the issue? If not, please clarify this.